# Advice on AJAX updating hundreds (>720) of data fields

Tags: jquery

I manage a website for a local sports group. During last year's LiveUpdate tournament I manually updated the score progress for hours a day over 3 days. Although enjoyable, it's time for a better solution.

[This mockup](http://goo.gl/4nFsY), shows one out of the six matches running simultaneously. 
That's 6 matches, each with 18 holes, each with 5 data points (team 1 score, team 2 score, match progess, time, comment, comment replies) > 720 data points.

I'm looking for general advice and/or specific solutions on updating hundreds of data points with AJAX. I haven't yet decided on how to store the data, though I'm leaning towards XML.

Any and all advice to help make the final decisions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this question, here's what I ended up with:

- All data stored in MySQL
- MySQL structure built with DbSchema.
- Easily maintained with Xataface front end.
- AJAX calls every XX seconds to a PHP script that pulls all updated data from MySQL, writes it into an XML file using standard PHP XML DOM.
- The resulting XML file is parsed by the Taconite jQuery plugin and updates all data fields.